WINSCP list directory function creation in Powershell
Hello I appreciate this may be better suited for the WINSCP forums however someone here may be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to create a function that when called will list the objects in a remote directory. I am basing it off a function i created that downloads files but instead of calling the GetFiles method I am just calling the ListDirectory method.
The issue is when i run this function (with the variables already containing the relevant Ftp server hostname, UN/PW, SSHhostkeyfingerprint and FTP Directory) it doesn't error out but nothing happens
Function SFTPSessionOpen {

param

    (

    [string]$FtpServer,

    [string]$FtpDirectory,

    [string]$FtpUsername,

    [string]$FtpPassword,

    [string]$FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint



    )   
## Load WinSCP .NET assembly

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll") | Out-Null

## Setup session options

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions

$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp

$sessionOptions.HostName = $FtpServer

$sessionOptions.UserName = $FtpUsername

$sessionOptions.Password = $FtpPassword

$sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = $FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$mycollection = @()

try {

## Connect

$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$mycollection = $session.ListDirectory($FtpDirectory).Files

}

finally {

$session.Dispose()

}

}

I would have expected it to pull the directory list into the $mycollection variable when called but it remains empty. If i run part of the function individually (establish a session then use $session.ListDirectory it will list files)
Any help is appreciated!
##Prod
$FtpServer = "clientftp.rimbees.com"

$FtpUsername = "Username"
$Ftppassword = "Password"

$FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 Wi2ZFNQvI6xvklKznGlZ1Cv5vGB3tV0dtAPH6TFMrJk"

$FtpDirectory = "./"

$mycollection = SFTPSessionOpen -FtpServer $FtpServer -FtpUsername $FtpUsername -FtpPassword $Ftppassword -FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint $FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint -FtpDirectory $FtpDirectory

I call the function with the pre defined variables and expect it to at least establish a session. The end goal is that i run it and it display all the files on the remote directory (in this case root folder)
It works when i run the section in separate blocks however as a function ( i tried using a breakpoint and debugging) it seems to never establish the connection/open the session.

This isn't reddit, so you're definitely in the wrong place :)

put a } catch { $error[0] see if you are getting any errors.

I'm silly, I originally posted this (or tried to) on r/Powershell and copied the original body. My apologies. I will add a catch clause to capture the error thank you

Your function does not RETURN anything. It misses return $mycollection.

As silly as it sounds, you can't do it all in one step. You must do it in two steps. e.g.:
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$directory = $session.ListDirectory($FtpDirectory)

foreach ($fileInfo in $directory.Files)
{
    Write-Host ("$($fileInfo.Name) with size $($fileInfo.Length), " +
        "permissions $($fileInfo.FilePermissions) and " +
        "last modification at $($fileInfo.LastWriteTime)")
}

You first have to call the Session.ListDirectory() method. This will return a RemoteDirectoryInfo object.
(speculation) I believe because of how WinSCP, .NET, and COM work, to return read-only properties, the ListDirectory() method, needs to execute first in order to create the RemoteDirectoryInfo object to be returned, otherwise, you are actually accessing an empty class definition e.g. empty, and not a "filled" RemoteDirectoryInfo object.
But, the other key thing here is that the ListDirectory() method could throw an exception that is different than a simple empty RemoteDirectoryInfo object. It an throw for example a SessionRemoteException e.g. Listing of remote directory has failed. This is an error message that you may want to capture in your try..catch block to indicate that there is an issue with the connection as opposed to listing "0 files".
The second step is to then take the directory listing and enumerate it however you need it.
Some more information here: Session.ListDirectory Method
Also, if you need to list by wildcard, recursively, or other ways, you may want to look at the Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles Method as an alternate way of listing your files.

In the end I followed HAL9256's example. Believe maybe his theory on how the LidDirectory() method needs to execure first in order to create the RemoteDirectoryInfo object was correct. I just modified some things as I only wanted the Name, Date modified and size of the items.
## Function to Establish to List Remote Directory
    ## -----------------------------------------------------------

    Function SFTPListDirectory {
    param
        (
        [string]$FtpServer,
        [string]$RemoteDirectory,
        [string]$FtpUsername,
        [string]$FtpPassword,
        [string]$FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint
        
                
        )   
        $DirResults = @()
    
 ## Load WinSCP .NET assembly
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll") | Out-Null
     
        ## Setup session options
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
        $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        $sessionOptions.HostName = $FtpServer
        $sessionOptions.UserName = $FtpUsername
        $sessionOptions.Password = $FtpPassword
        $sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = $FtpSshHostKeyFingerprint
     
        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 

        
try {
         ## Connect
              $session.Open($SessionOptions)
              $directory = $session.ListDirectory($RemoteDirectory)

              foreach ($file in $directory) {

              $DirResults += New-Object Psobject -property @{Name = $file.Name; LastModified = $file.Lastwritetime; Size = $file.length}
}

            
         }

         catch [Exception]
        {
            $Return.StandardOutput = $_.Exception.Message
            $Return.IsSuccess = $false
        }
         
        finally
        {
            ## Disconnect and cleanup
            $session.Dispose()
        }
        
        Return $Return
        }

